# MVC Modifying a EF data through a navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I recently finished an MVC course on udemy that built a video rental app.  He covered how to check out a movie but left on our own to figure out how check it back in.

I have a Customer model:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter customer's name.")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        [Min18YearsIfAMember]  
        public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }

        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }  

        [Display(Name = "Membership Type")]
        public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; } 
    }
```

A Movie model:

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Genre")]
        [Required]
        public byte GenreId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Number in Stock")]
        [Range(1, 20)]
        public byte NumberInStock { get; set; }

        public byte NumberAvailable { get; set; }
    }
```

And a Rental model that contains a customer and a movie:

```
public class Rental
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateRented { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateReturned { get; set; }
    }
```

I made a view that will display the active rentals and I made a Delete action that will delete it as if the movie has been turned in, but I can't figure out how to put that movie back in stock by increasing the number of available movies(Movies.NumberAvailable). I tried to do it in the same action as the Delete action but I'm having no luck.  Here's the Delete action:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)  
        {
            Rental rental = _context.Rentals.Find(id);
            //var movie = _context.Movies.Where(m => rental.Movie.Id.Contains(m.Id));
            rental.Movie.NumberAvailable++;

            _context.Rentals.Remove(rental);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
```

I tried to pull out just that movie into it's own variable and add 1 to that but the `rental.Movie.Id` part popped an error saying it doesn't have a definition for  Contain.  If I run it as it is above, I get an exception at `rental.Movie.NumberAvailable++;` saying The 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Does anyone have any ideas on I can do to fix this?  Yes, I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
Rental rental = _context.Rentals.Where(r => r.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
rental.Movie.NumberAvailable++;
```

Comment: This gives the same result.  rental is assigned a MovieId, but Movie is null.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple approaches I can suggest to tackle problems like this.

1. Track the movie instances and their status and calculate the totals on demand.

This would be something like a Movie class, but then each movie would have a collection of MovieDisc for instance:

```
public class MovieDisc
{
   public int MovieDiscId{ get; set; }
   public bool InStock { get; set; }
   public string Barcode { get; set; }
}
```

Basically as movies are checked out or scanned in, their barcode identifies the "disc" or instance and sets the InStock. From the movie side:

```
public class Movie 
{
   // ...

   public virtual ICollection<MovieDisc> Discs {get; internal set;} = new List<MovieDisc>();
   public byte NumberInStock 
   { 
      get { return Discs.Count(x => x.InStock); }
   }

   public byte NumberAvailable 
   { 
      get { return Discs.Count(x => !x.InStock); }
   }
}
```

The caveat of this approach is that to use these properties, the Discs collection needs to be eager loaded, or will trip a lazy load.

2. Adopt a DDD approach to the entities.

Domain Driven Design essentially adds controls to how state changes in the domain. Rather than using individual setters for values, you use methods or actions on the domain entity to validate and control the valid, and complete changes allowed against the domain.

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; private set; }

    [Display(Name = "Genre")]
    [Required]
    public byte GenreId { get; private set; }

    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; private set; }

    public DateTime DateAdded { get; private set; }

    [Display(Name = "Number in Stock")]
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public byte NumberInStock { get; private set; }

    public byte NumberAvailable { get; private set; }

    public void RentOneOut()
    {
       if (NumberInStock <= 0)
          throw new InvalidOperation("Cannot rent out a movie that has no stock.");
       if (NumberAvailable <= 0)
          throw new InvalidOperation("All movie copies are out.");

       NumberAvailable -= 1;
    }

    public void ReturnOneIn()
    {
       if (NumberInStock <= 0)
          throw new InvalidOperation("Cannot return a movie that has no stock.");
       if (NumberAvailable >= NumberInStock)
          throw new InvalidOperation("All movie copies are already in. Stocktake needed.");

       NumberAvailable += 1;
    }
}
```

Note all setters are private. (or internal if you want to enable unit testing) The objective is to express valid operations against a domain entity as a method. This ensures that multiple checks and updates are performed as a whole so that multiple properties can be updated together rather than risking leaving an entity in an incomplete state.

This might be more practical for your rental scenario:

```
public function ReturnRental(Rental rental)
{
   if (rental == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("rental");

   rental.Return();
}

// In Rental:
public class Rental
{
   // ...  private setters, like in Movie.

   public void Return()
   {
      Movie.ReturnOneIn();
      DateReturned = DateTime.Today;
   }
}
```

You'd want to handle the scenario where the return failed for whatever reason. (data state out of sync)

Hopefully that gives you a few ideas.

Comment: That seems a bit more complicated than what I was thinking.  Is there no way to increment NumberAvailable from the Delete action?

Comment: Using references between the entities you can, but it leaves the code open to ending up in an invalid state. Rental references a Movie, so when you find a Rental to delete you can use: `rental.Movie.NumberAvailable += 1;` then remove the rental from context.Rentals and call `SaveChanges`. However, this leaves your code open to bugs as everywhere rentals are added/removed/modified you need to balance out the changes to their past and present Movie association. (I.e. a feature to change a rental from one movie to another.) You can code for it, but as it matures, so does the risk of issues.